# how to dropdown button with images only without any text in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, button, dropdown

I am beginner in flutter. I want drop with images with visa and master card images. No text. Text can be there as label like select text, then 2 options . Here what I tried.

Here is declaration

[image]

Dropdown code that I tried

[image]

Currently I m not taking images online. So I have static images field declared. I want changes in this code. Please suggest what changes I needed here.

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, error or other text

Comment: facing errors while posting so I had to post images.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use your image as value of dropdown, you can also use some other data type like string.

```dart
DropdownButton<String>(
    value: 'visa',
    onChanged:(value){},
      items:[
           DropdownMenuItem(
           value:'visa',
           child:Image.network()//your visa image,
        ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
          value:'master',
          child:Image.network()//your master image,
        ),],
);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I expected other answer.